# Configuring replica set in a multi-data center

Tags: mongodb, replication

We have the following multi data-center Scenario

```
Node1 --- Node3
    |        |
    |        |
    |        |
   ---      ---
  Node2    Node4
```

`Node1` and `Node3` form a Replica (sort of) Set ( *for high availability* )

`Node 2/Node 4` are Priority 0 members (*They should never become Primaries - Solely for read purpose*)

Caveat -- what is the best way to design such a situation, since `Node 2` and `Node4` are not accessible to one another, given the way we configured our VPN/Firewalls;

essentially ruling out any heartbeat between `Node2` and `Node4`.

Thanks Much

Comment: So to my understanding, node1/3 are in the same data center and node2/4 are in another 2 data centers. Can I ask why Node2/4 are not able to access each other? because this way they can't receive heartbeat from each other.

Comment: yep it's the way our DataCenters are configured, there is no access across data centers from Node 2 - Node 4 :( and you're spot on this also pertains to heartbeat. Since we can't open any ports.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got in mind:

1. Don't keep even members in a set. Thus you need another [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/) or set one of node2/4 to [non-voting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#replica-set-non-voting-members) member.
2. As I'm using C# driver, I'm not sure you are using the same technology to build your application. Anyway, it turns out C# driver obtain a complete available server list from seeds (servers you provided in connection string) and tries to load-balancing requests to all of them. In your situation, I guess you would have application servers running in all 3 data centers. However, you probably don't want, for example, node 1 to accept connections from a different data center. That would significantly  slow down the application. So you need some further settings:

   1. Set node 3/4 to [hidden](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-hidden-replica-set-member/) nodes.
   2. For applications running in the same data center with node 3/4, don't config the replicaSet parameter in connection string. But config the readPreference=secondary. If you need to write, you'll have to config another connection string to primary node.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the votes of 2 and 4 also 0 then it should act, in failover as though 1 and 2 are only eligible. If you set them to hidden you have to forceably connect to them, MongoDB drivers will intentionally avoid them normally.

Other than that node 2 and 4 have direct access to whatever would be the primary as such I see no other problem.

Comment: Thanks... so even though Node 2 / Node 4 / Node 1 and Node 3 are all part of a Replica Set.  Essentially by setting the votes for Node 2 and Node 4 to Zero along with Priority as 0 makes them not require a heartbeat ?. So basically it means that either Node 1 and Node 3 will be primary and Node 2 / Node 4 essentially will be used only for READ operations, and they won't require any heartbeat. So no need of an open connection between Node 2 and Node 4 ?

Comment: @DurgaDeep it makes them require a heart beat but the rest of the set won't worry too much if they are down, pluis you won't get a partition between them. However, yes node 2 and 4 will be for only reads then, I would add to my statement that I would add a third member to your primary dc where node 1 and 3 sit else you will get problems in elections